# TikZ: issue with lines in foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops, foreach

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (h) at (0, 3);
  \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);

  \draw (O) -- +(-3, 0);
  \draw[-latex] (O) -- +(3, 0) node[right, font = \scriptsize] {$x$};
  \draw[-latex] (O) -- +(0, 4) node[above, font = \scriptsize] {$z$};

  \foreach \x/\s in {-1.5/{-}, 1.5/{+}}{
    \draw (\x, 0) -- +(0, -0.1) node[below, font = \scriptsize] (l\s) at
    (\x, 0) {$\s\frac{\ell}{2}$};
  }

  \draw (l-.center) -- (h);
  \draw (l+.center) -- (h);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My final two line are drawing from the labels not the x intercept line where I would anticipate.  How can this be correct?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `coordinate` inside a path to name the exact coordinates. You were naming the node *below* the desired coordinates.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (h) at (0, 3);
  \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);

  \draw (O) -- +(-3, 0);
  \draw[-latex] (O) -- +(3, 0) node[right, font = \scriptsize] {$x$};
  \draw[-latex] (O) -- +(0, 4) node[above, font = \scriptsize] {$z$};

  \foreach \x/\s in {-1.5/{-}, 1.5/{+}}{
    \draw (\x, 0) coordinate (l\s) -- +(0, -0.1) node[below, font = \scriptsize] at
    (\x, 0) {$\s\frac{\ell}{2}$};
  }

  \draw (l-.center) -- (h);
  \draw (l+.center) -- (h);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Output]

Comment: Do you know why the node didn't work with .center?

Comment: You should try `.north` for the desire result. It also works.

`.center` refers to the center of the node with text. Since the node is place below, it is expected that the line will go "below" the axis too.